# How to read data from firebase inside AlertDialog widget?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to read data from firebase inside an AlertDialog in flutter, when a button is pressed, and then update it afterwards.

I have tried using a StreamBuilder, but nothing happens

```dart
  new FlatButton(
      child: const Text('+ Add'),
      onPressed: () {
        StreamBuilder(
            stream: Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(user.uid).collection('Filtre').document('ChooseSelf').snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              var TypeSelfFilters = snapshot.data;
              List<String> ListOfTypeSelf = List.from(TypeSelfFilters["Personer"]);
              ListOfTypeSelf.add("value of TextFormField");
              Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(user.uid).collection('Filtre').document('ChooseSelf').updateData({'Personer': ListOfTypeSelf});
            }
        );
        Navigator.pop(context);
      }
  );
```

I do not get any errors, but the code inside the StreamBuilder is not executed for some reason.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Hm... It looks to me that you are expecting to get the data when the use taps on `FlatButton`.

Let's look what happens:

1. tap on FlatButton
2. Instantiate a `StreamBuilder`
3. Start getting data from Firestore
4. Do some Firestore magic, update date
5. Then close dialog by `navigator.pop()`

**Problem:** you call `navigator.pop()` right after Instantiation of `StreamBuilder`. StreamBuilder has to wait somewhat to get the data. If you pop a route, and with that destroying your alert dialog, the builder callback will not be called. So the actual sequence of things happening is: `Tap -> Instantiate StreamBuilder -> pop route`

**Recommendation:** why wrap your computation in a StreamBuilder? You could do:

```dart
onPressed: () {
  Firestore.instance.collection('users')/*...*/.snapshots().then((snapshot) async {
    // then branch is executed once snapshot is retrieved from firestore
    var TypeSelfFilters = snapshot.data;
    // do some more computation and magic
    await Firestore.instance.collection/*...*/.updateData();
    // wait for updateData to finish
    Navigator.pop(context); // this context is not the context inside the StreamBuilder
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I still get the error "The method 'then' isn't defined for the class 'Stream'."

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Daniel V. i found a solution:

```
var myData = Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(user.uid).collection('Filtre').document('ChooseSelf').snapshots().first;
                myData.then((snapshot) async {
                  var TypeSelfFilters = snapshot.data;
                  List<String> ListOfTypeSelf = List.from(TypeSelfFilters["Personer"]);
                  ListOfTypeSelf.add("bare en test");
                  Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(user.uid).collection('Filtre').document('ChooseSelf').updateData({'Personer': ListOfTypeSelf});
                  Navigator.pop(context); // this context is not the context inside the StreamBuilder
                });
                }
                )
```